# monacaのandroidで、LINEの紹介機能がうまく起動しない。

Tags: javascript, monaca, html

現在、monacaを使用してLINEの紹介機能を作成しています。
iosではLINEの紹介機能は作成できたのですが、androidではLINEが起動しなかったです。

プログラムはhtmlやjavascirptを使用したのですがどれも思った動きにはならなかったです。
以下は試したプログラムとなります。Cordovaバージョンは5.2です。

```
<a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?ここに文章とURL"></a>

<a href="javascript:var str = 'http://line.me/R/msg/text/'+ encodeURIComponent('送りたい文章'); window.open(str, '_blank', 'location=yes');"></a>
```

monacaを使用してandroidでLINEの紹介機能をするには他にどのような方法があるのでしょうか？
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

記載コード後者において、`window.open()`の呼び出しで`_blank`ではなく、`_system`を指定して外部ブラウザ経由または直接LINEを起動して、メッセージを送ることができます。
※`InAppBrowser`プラグインが必要。

```
window.open(str, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: いつも、回答ありがとうございます。意図した動きとなりました。

Comment: @donadesu 解決したようでしたら回答を承認してください。